# Report with filter 'yesterday' produces no result

Tags: civireport

When I create a report of contributions I can select a filter on 'Receive Date' of yesterday and any transactions with yesterday's Receive Date will be displayed. If I select a filter on 'Transaction Date' of yesterday no transactions are displayed even though there are transactions with a Transaction Date of yesterday.

In looking at the Contribution Table the transaction date is not shown in the table.

Can someone throw some light on this apparent issue?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction_date field lives in civicrm_financial_item. Not sure that helps you much though.

Comment: No It doesn't help - it seems that the date is able to be selected in the report filter but it doesn't work. Seems to me to be an error. I am only a 'configurer' and not a 'developer' unfortunately so I am not able to help solve the problem. All I can do is report it.